# thymeleaf evaluate string as variable

Tags: thymeleaf

suppose I have a thymeleaf fragment named "reference" that takes a parameter referenceNumber="1" and in my model I have "reference1_firstName" = "Bob"

```
<div ... th:fragment="reference(referenceNumber)">
   Reference <div th:text="${referenceNumber}"/> first name is <div th:text="${'reference' + referenceNumber + '_firstName'}".>
</div>
```

in the obviously incorrect example above I would like to print out "Reference 1 first name is Bob". It seems so simple, I can do it in several other languages, but so far my search has come up empty for thymeleaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple ways to do this.

[Preprocessing](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing):

```
<span th:text="${reference__${referenceNumber}___firstName}" />
```

[`#ctx` basic object](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-a-expression-basic-objects):

```
<span th:text="${#ctx.getVariable('reference' + referenceNumber + '_firstName')}" />
<span th:text="${#ctx['reference' + referenceNumber + '_firstName']}" />
```

Or if you intend to access variables this way, use a `Map` instead of variables.

Comment: Thank you for your help, preprocessing worked like a charm, and then as you suggested I refactored the code to a list of references and iterated over them as I should have done in the first place. Thanks!